# General error: 1651 Query cache is disabled; restart the server with query_cache_type=1 to enable it

Tags: mysql, query-cache

I am getting this error when I'm trying to connect using PDO.

```
General error: 1651 Query cache is disabled; restart the server with query_cache_type=1 to enable it
```

I do not have access to MySQL terminal. I only have access to phpmyadmin via cPanel.

How can I fix this?

I tried this :-

```
try
{
  $s = $conn->query("SET query_cache_type = 1");
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

But this didn't work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please be more specific. What does it mean, it "didn't work"?

Comment: @JohannesMüller

I still get the same error, even after adding that code above.

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange behavior of `query_cache_type` such that cannot be enabled if it wasn't enabled when the mysqld process started. But if it was enabled at startup, you can set `query_cache_type` "off" and then back on again if you need to.

That said, I would strongly encourage you to reconsider using the query cache at all. [MySQL 8.0 has retired support for the query cache](http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-retiring-support-for-the-query-cache/) and removed it from the product. It's still a feature in MySQL 5.7, but it's deprecated as of 5.7.20.

Answer (score 0):

On mac it worked after executing below command

```
sudo /your-path-to-mysql/mysql.server start --query-cache-type=1

sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start --query-cache-type=1
```

try this!